# Joda DateTime to java.sql.Timestamp ignore timezone?

Tags: postgresql, scala, datetime, timestamp, jodatime

In a scala program, I receive from client side a specific date for instance:

`2013-10-20T23:59:59.999Z`

and I really want to keep this date when saving into DB and not convert to local, so this line:

`debug("--sql timestamp: " +  new Timestamp(reading.timestamp.getMillis()))`

is printing out: `2013-10-21 02:59:59.999`(I am in Romania).

Is there any way I can ignore timezone?

Answer (score 2):

This is [`Timestamp.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29) behavior. `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date` and in its `toString()` method it uses, in particular, [`super.getHours()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Date.java#Date.getHours%28%29), which, [according to javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29), returns hours interpreted in local timezone - exactly as you observe.

However, internally `Timestamp` still holds correct timestamp value. There may be problems with storing it to the database, though. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific) answer.

Answer (score 2):

`2013-10-20T23:59:59.999Z` and `2013-10-21 02:59:59.999` are actually the same time: `2013-10-20T23:59:59.999Z` is in the [UTC time zone (Z)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706777/372643), whereas the second one is relative, and expressed as your local time zone (UTC+3 then in Romania).

In PostgreSQL, you should store your timestamps as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (`TIMESTAMPTZ`) in your database to handle this. You'll always be able to print it out later in the time zone you choose then (e.g. UTC). (You might be interested in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068023/372643) to understand why the storage type matters.)

If you want to print out the timestamp in the UTC/Z time zone again, `new DateTime(millis, DateTimeZone.UTC)` should help (with Joda Time).